# Show that the value of the following definite integral is greater than 0.405

Tags: calculus, integration, inequality, definite-integrals, approximation

Given $F(0) = \frac{1}{\pi D} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{D}} \frac{\sin^2[Dy]}{\sin^2[y]} dy$. Assume D is some constant.

Using the following properties prove:  $F(0) \geq \frac{4}{\pi^2} > 0.405$

Properties:

1. $|\sin [x]| \leq |x| ~\forall x \in \mathrm{R}$,
2. $|\sin [x]| \geq |(\frac{2}{\pi})x| ~\forall x \in [0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$
3. $|\sin [x]| \geq |-(\frac{2}{\pi})x+2| ~\forall x \in [\frac{\pi}{2},\pi]$

I did not understand the following proof:
[image]

Note: This is not my homework problem. I encountered this calculation in a paper and got stuck.

Comment: You split the integral at $\pi/(2D)$ into two parts. The argument $Dy$ varies between $0$ and $\pi/2$ in the first and between $\pi/2$ and $\pi$ in the second integral. You bound from below the sine with argument $Dy$ using the second inequality in the first, and using the third inequality in the second integral. For both integrals you bound $1/\sin y$ from below by the first inequality.

Comment: @Gary I tried doing the same, I could not arrive at the desired result.

Comment: I see. What is written in the paper is incorrect. It should start $$
F(0) \ge \frac{1}{{\pi D}}\int_0^{\frac{\pi }{{2D}}} {\left( {\frac{2}{\pi }Dy} \right)^2 /y^2 dy}  + \frac{1}{{\pi D}}\int_{\frac{\pi }{{2D}}}^{\frac{\pi }{D}} {\left( {\frac{2}{\pi }Dy - 2} \right)^2 /y^2 dy} .$$ Try to continue and see if it leads to the claim.

Comment: @Gary I got 1st term as $\frac{2}{\pi^2}$, but could not get  $\frac{2}{\pi^2}$ for the second term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right in your last comment. For the second bit one has $\frac{{6 - 8\log 2}}{{\pi ^2 }}$, so the whole thing is at least $\frac{8}{{\pi ^2 }}(1 - \log 2) \approx 0.248$, which is weaker than what is claimed in the paper. However, you can use the following simpler argument to obtain a better lower bound:
$$
\frac{1}{{\pi D}}\int_0^{\frac{\pi }{D}} {\frac{{\sin ^2 (Dy)}}{{\sin ^2 y}}dy}  = \frac{1}{{\pi D^2 }}\int_0^\pi  {\frac{{\sin ^2 t}}{{\sin ^2 (t/D)}}dt}  \ge \frac{1}{{\pi D^2 }}\int_0^\pi  {\frac{{\sin ^2 t}}{{(t/D)^2 }}dt}  = \frac{1}{\pi }\int_0^\pi  {\frac{{\sin ^2 t}}{{t^2 }}dt} \\ = 0.4514116667 \ldots  > \frac{4}{{\pi ^2 }} = 0.4052847345 \ldots  > 0.405.
$$

Comment: can you please elaborate the derivation of  $\frac{1}{\pi }\int_0^\pi  {\frac{{\sin ^2 t}}{{t^2 }}dt}$

Comment: First, I made the change of integration variables $y=t/D$. Next, I used the fact that $\sin^2 x < x^2$ for all real $x$. With this I arrived at a lower bound which is independent of $D$. This is the integral you are asking about. I just used Wolfram Alpha to compute it numerically and it gave me that value. There is no way to express that integral in terms of simple objects. Interestingly though $$
\int_0^\pi  {\frac{{\sin ^2 t}}{{t^2 }}dt}  = \int_0^{2\pi } {\frac{{\sin t}}{t}dt}.
$$